# How to regex text between custom format title with new line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to grab todo items from the following example text.

```
|| This is title ||

- item1
- item2
- item3

|| This is another title ||
```

I've tried with `/|| This is title ||\n\n(.*)+/` but it only grabs `item1` and I honestly have no idea how to write regex for the `|| This is another title ||

I would like to grab item1~3

Comment: why don't you just replace the `|| This is title ||` and `|| This is another title ||` parts to `''`

Comment: @Jejun Well, wish I have control over the content..but I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the title and the items separated in two groups, you could use a [***tempered greedy token***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) (originally [**from here**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)) as in

```
^\|\|\s+([^\n|]+)\s+\|\|((?:(?!^\|\|).)+)
```

This captures the title in the first group and all of the items in the second. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/T6VHLB/1/) (and mind the singleline mode!).

---

Broken down, this reads:

```
^\|\|\s+            # start of the line, "||" and whitespace
([^\n|]+)           # anything not "|" nor a newline - the title
\s+\|\|             # whitespace, "||"
(
    (?:(?!^\|\|).)+ # a neg. lookahead (?!...) that makes sure that no
)                   # line is captured that starts with "||"
```

Afterwards, you could simply get all your items with `^-(.+)` from within the second group.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be repeatedly matching all lines that start with `-` in a group.

Then you might trim the result, and split on a newline.

```
^\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\n((?:\n- .*)+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\n` Match `||`  till  `||` at the end followed by the first newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\n- .*)+` Match a newline, `-`  and the rest of the line
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTais8/1)

```js
const regex = /^\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\n((?:\n- .*)+)/gm;
const str = `|| This is title ||

- item1
- item2
- item3

|| This is another title ||`;

Array.from(
  str.matchAll(regex), m => console.log(m[1].trim().split("\n"))
);
```